# Click a button if <div> tag has four buttons , when other button are not displayed in <div> tag using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, browser-automation

In `<div>` tag there are four buttons, but only one button is displayed at a time. Once one button is clicked, the page navigates to another page and another button in `<div>` tag is displayed . I need to click Start button firstly. For that I used `//*[@id='btn-student-start-assignment']`

Html code :

```html
<div id="student-paper-controls" class="paperControls clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <button id="ktOnDemandBtn" class="btn btn-primary-alt ktOnDemandClass" style="display:none" type="button" tabindex="0" />
        <button id="stuControlsBackToTasksButton" class="btn btn-default-alt prBackToTaskButtonClass hidden" type="button" tabindex="0">
          < Back to Tasks</button>
            <button id="btn-student-submit-assignment" class="btn btn-student-submit-assignment-cls btn-primary" type="button" tabindex="0">Submit</button>
            <button id="btn-student-start-assignment" class="btn btn-primary-alt" type="button" tabindex="0">Start</button>
            <button id="btn-student-edit-save" class="btn btn-primary-alt" type="button" tabindex="0">Edit / Save As New</button>
      </div>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What  is the error you getting?

Comment: No code errors.. only thing is <button id...> 's didn't recognize the element.. when code run it says "failed to find element"

Comment: Given HTML code displays all four buttons in one go. You can check SO's Run Code Snippet. Can you share actual URL of application instead of html code?